# SQL add text to numeric column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if this is even possible but I have a query that joins two table and compares two data sets, current month vs previous month. Where I have new data the previous column produces a Null.

I have been trying to replace NULL with the text 'New Account'. However I am aware that I am trying to force a text value into a numeric column.

So I'm just wondering if this is even possible as I haven't found anything online to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  `COALESCE()`.

Comment: Sounds like something you should be handling in your presentation layer in my opinion. Leave the data types as they are in your database, and when your application receives the value `NULL` then display `'New Account'`.

Comment: Please, provide an example with DDL but... in any case, you cannot compare a text like 'New Account' with a number

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I tried COALESCE and got the following: Error converting data type varchar to float.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I did wonder if that might be the best option but wanted to check in case there was a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Angel M, I think you have taken my post literally. I'm not trying to compare New Account to a number the comparison has already been done and produces a Null. I just want to make the data more user friendly by replacing the Null with 'New Account'

Comment: FYI, `ISNULL` is another option here, assuming you don't need to compare more than two values. I'm trying to track down my info on the matter, but there's some subtle differences between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` based on the data types of the arguments passed. IIRC `ISNULL` is less susceptible to such issues (or at least "differently susceptible").

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on Gordon's and Larnu's comments.

No, you can't **UPDATE** a numeric column with text.  You can, however, change the final presentation of the value.

Please note that the final result is a string and not a numeric value.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (25)
,(null)

Select SomeCol = coalesce(left(SomeCol,10),'New Account')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol
25
New Account
```

Comment: `Please note that the final result is a string and not a numeric value.` This is key here, that means that you can't use the numbers in further calculations. Prefer to do so as close to the presentation layer as possible.

Comment: @Alejandro Agree 1,000%.    :)